# Excel - Drop-down list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given the following Excel tables

- **Table A**

| Cat | Sub |
| --- | --- |
| A | s1 |
| A | s2 |
| A | s3 |
| B | s1 |
| B | s1 |
| C | s1 |

- **table B**

| Cat | Sub |
| --- | --- |
| A | ▽ drop-down |
| A | ▽ drop-down |

How can I add a drop-down list in B[Sub] with the unique values of A[Sub] having A[Cat] = B[Cat] as a match. That is, the result of the following query

```
SELECT A.Sub
FROM A
JOIN B on A.cat = B.cat
```

In this case, the values of Sub[B] should report s1, s2, s3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UNIQUE() function returns an array and data validation does not work with arrays.
Then I had the of UNIQUE returned into a cell and in the data validation I created the list by spill referencing to the cell containing a UNIQUE function.

Below is a screenshot with the solution

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try use this formula in the list format in the data validation:

```
=UNIQUE(OFFSET($B$1,MATCH($H$2,$A$1:$A$7,0)-1,0,COUNTIF($A$1:$A$7,$H$2),1))
```

- $H$2 - is the value you looking for (A or B).
- $A$1:$A$7 - is the range you're looking in.

when you implement this formula in the list option in the data validation it should work just fine. when you will select "A" it would show the values you want and also for "B" and so on. I'm adding a picture for you to see:

[look at this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weteM.png)